# Setting @name to scheduler or website, leads to layout not found

Tags: wffm

Attached the Sitedefinition.config we are using.
if we have the patch:before="site[@name='scheduler']", then the home page itself is not loading. We are experiencing "Layout Not Found"

if we have patch:before="site[@name='website']", we are able to login to the site and navigate. But for some page we are receiving the "Layout error".(These pages are redirected by WFFM Custom save action)

Note : We have multisite in single sitecore instance.

[image: Sitedefinition.config]

Comment: Do you have any other custom site definitions? Have you made any changes to the `website` site

Comment: We dont have any custom site definitions and no changes were done to website site

Comment: So is there any scenario when you can access all your pages? Are you sure all the layouts are published?

Comment: All the layout are published. This is happening only while we call the wffm save action and on success redirection.

Comment: And is the url correct after redirection? Or some `/sitecore/content..` in the url or maybe other issues with it? Can you open the page using same url if you just copy it into the browser url bar?

Comment: URL that was returned while reading the success url field in WFFM(General Link), we are facing the issue.
/<Sitename>/Home/<page level1>/<page level 2>/<page level 3>
here we are reading the success field url and redirecting

Comment: If the URL is Internal URL -- Works Fine
Sitecore/Content/<Sitename>/Home/<page level1>/<page level 2>/<page level 3>

Comment: Will it be the difference in redirecting or url formation of using the General link and internal link